# Find a File and Run it using the results of the first command?

Tags: terminal, command

I was wondering how to use the command mdfind and use the results of that to run it:

Example: mdfind -name something.jar && java -Xmx256m -jar (the results of the search)

Answer (score 1):

mdfind -name something.jar | xargs java -Xmx256m -jar